# Open vds file with three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, autocad

Can anyone tell if its possible to open an VDS-file with three.js and how to do it? I would like to develop an application where you can select different nodes in a 3D-model. We make use of AutoCAD and SAP. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: SAP is a huge software company. Which SAP software?

Answer (score 1):

three.js is a library, not an application that can open a file format. There are some JSON input strings that can be converted into three.js 3D models.

The [Autodesk A360 Viewer](https://360.autodesk.com/viewer) don't open this format.. do you have any other alternative? I'm not aware of other converters (from engineer files to three.js webgl).